# Image edge detection algorithm: creating a 2D mesh

Tags: java, c#, algorithm, image-processing, xna

Let's first start off with what I am trying to do.  I would like to be able to take PNG file with a transparent background and find anywhere from 90 to 360 points along the edge of the subject of the image.  Here is a rough example of what I mean.  Given this image of Mario and Yoshi:

[image: Mario and Yoshi]

I want to make a circle that is centered at the center of the image with a diameter slightly larger than the largest side of the image to serve as a reference.  Then, I want to go around the circle at set intervals, and trace a line towards the center until it hits a non-transparent pixel.  Here is what that would look like:

[image: Mario and Yoshi Traced]

I have attempted to implement this a few different times, all of which failed, and I was hoping to get some guidance or insight as to what I am doing wrong.  Here is an image of the math I am using behind the code (sorry if the quality is not great, I don't have a scanner):

[image: Math]

The Line 1 is either the top, bottom, left or right edge of the image, and Line 2 goes through the center of the circle at the given angle.  The point where lines 1 and 2 intersect should be on the edge of the image, and is where we should start looking for the edge of the image's subject.

Here is the code that I came up with from this idea.  I did it in Java because BufferedImage is really easy to use, but I am going to translate this over to C# (XNA) for the final product.

```
public class Mesh {

private int angleA, angleB, angleC, angleD;
private BufferedImage image;
private Point center;
public ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();

public Mesh(BufferedImage image) {
    center = new Point(image.getWidth() / 2, image.getHeight() / 2);
    angleA = (int) (Math.atan(center.y / center.x) * (180 / Math.PI));
    angleB = 180 - angleA;
    angleC = 180 + angleA;
    angleD = 360 - angleA;
    this.image = image;
    for(int angle = 0; angle <= 360; angle+=4){
        Point point = getNext(angle);
        if(point != null) points.add(point);
    }
}

private Point getNext(int angle) {
    double radians = angle * Math.PI / 180;
    double xStep = Math.cos(radians);
    double yStep = Math.sin(radians);
    int addX = angle >= 90 && angle <= 270 ? 1 : -1;
    int addY = angle >= 0 && angle <= 180 ? 1 : -1;
    double x, y;

    if (xStep != 0) {
        double slope = yStep / xStep;
        double intercept = center.y - (slope * center.x);
        if (angle >= angleA && angle <= angleB) {
            y = 0;
            x = -intercept / slope;
        } else if (angle > angleB && angle < angleC) {
            x = 0;
            y = intercept;
        } else if (angle >= angleC && angle <= angleD) {
            y = image.getHeight() - 1;
            x = (y - intercept) / slope;
        } else {
            x = image.getWidth() - 1;
            y = slope * x + intercept;
        }
    } else {
        x = center.x;
        y = angle <= angleB ? 0 : image.getHeight();
    }

    if (x < 0) x = 0;
    if (x > image.getWidth() - 1) x = image.getWidth() - 1;
    if (y < 0) y = 0;
    if (y > image.getHeight() - 1) y = image.getHeight() - 1;

    double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - center.x, 2) + Math.pow(y - center.y, 2));
    double stepSize = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xStep, 2) + Math.pow(yStep, 2));
    int totalSteps = (int) Math.floor(distance / stepSize);

    for (int step = 0; step < totalSteps; step++) {
        int xVal = (int) x;
        int yVal = (int) y;
        if(xVal < 0) xVal = 0;
        if(xVal > image.getWidth() -1) xVal = image.getWidth() -1;
        if(yVal < 0) yVal = 0;
        if(yVal > image.getHeight()-1) yVal = image.getHeight() -1;
        int pixel = image.getRGB(xVal, yVal);

        if ((pixel >> 24) == 0x00) {
            x += (Math.abs(xStep) * addX);
            y += (Math.abs(yStep) * addY);
        } else {
            return new Point(xVal, yVal);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

The algorithm should be returning all positive points that are all ordered in counterclockwise rotation (and non-overlapping) but I have failed to get the desired output (this being my most recent attempt) so just to restate the question, is there a formalized way of doing this, or can someone find the mistake I made in my logic.  For visual reference, the *Mario and Yoshi Traced* image is sort of what the final output should look like, but with many more points (which would give more detail to the mesh).

Comment: Is the problem related to the determination of the bounding circle or the tracing of the converging rays ?

Comment: For the second part, you should consider using the Bresenham line drawing algorithm.

Comment: I want the rays to start on the bounding circle, then end on the edge of the image subject.  The hope is that the points would then be all in order so they could be a mesh of the image.

Comment: This was said in your post, you don't answer my question.

Comment: finding the circle is not the problem, I am having issue finding the the "mesh" sometimes the points are negative or cross the center, and it does not end up looking like an outline

Comment: Have you drawn the trajectories of your rays ? In mean the pixels that you access.

Comment: I am not certain what you are asking, but the way I am finding the trajectories is by taking the angle, and then flipping the sign of the x and y components. So 90 degrees would be [0,1] => [0,-1].  Then I just step towards the center with that increment.

Comment: I know what you are trying to do, but let the program draw it.